# Set product in stock and change the status to Enabled if qty is equals or greater than 1

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm trying to do this for a while, but there's something isn't right about this, I've tried to put it in stock and enable it but nothing is working for me, can someone give me a hint or pinpoint me to the issue?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Mr_StockEnhancements>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Mr_StockEnhancements>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
      <mr_stockenhancements>
        <class>Mr_StockEnhancements_Model</class>
      </mr_stockenhancements>
    </models>
    <events>
      <catalog_product_prepare_save>
        <observers>
          <Mr_StockEnhancements_Model_Observer>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Mr_StockEnhancements_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>stockEnhancements</method>
          </Mr_StockEnhancements_Model_Observer>
        </observers>
      </catalog_product_prepare_save>
    </events>
  </global>

</config>
```

And here's the observer:

```
class Mr_StockEnhancements_Model_Observer {

public function stockEnhancements(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

        $product   = $observer->getProduct();
        $stockData = $product->getStockData();

        //make sure stock qty is greater than zero.
        if (isset($stockData['qty']) && $stockData['qty'] >= 1) {

            $product->setStockData['is_in_stock'] = 1; //update to instock
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')
            ->updateAttributes(array($product->getId()), array('status' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED), $storeId);

            print_r($stockData['qty'], $product->StockData['is_in_stock']);
            exit;

        } else {
            Mage::getModel('catalog/product_status')->updateProductStatus($product->getProductId(), $storeId, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Is your observer working?

Comment: Yes, it's working, but it isn't doing what it should be doing.

Comment: Do you get desired data while printing?

Comment: Yes, but it isn't updating as it should be, that's the only problem.

Comment: Have you updated the event?

Comment: Yes, I did update the event as you instructed still, it doesn't update the "is_in_stock" to 1 as it should be and enable the product if it's disabled.

Comment: Take a look here http://prntscr.com/kovp4j

Comment: check edited code

Comment: I have added more code, please check

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`themename`.`catalog_product_entity_int`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_INT_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE ), query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_int` (`entity_type_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`value`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value` = VALUES(`value`)

Comment: Also, it does trigger the php to throw an error about the execution time limit, I think there's some sort of inefficiency in this code!

Answer (score 0):

You should use this observer on `catalog_product_save_after` event , replace your `<catalog_product_prepare_save>` tags in your xml to `<catalog_product_save_after>`

**EDIT :**

I think you've forgot to call `$product->save()` , so you should add it in the end of the code before `print_r`

**EDIT 2**

Also your stock update code doesn't seem right ..
Use following code ;

```
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');
$stockItem->assignProduct($product);
$stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 1);
$stockItem->setData('qty', 1);
$product->setStockItem($stockItem);
```

Comment: I tried this, but still, it isn't working, the observer is working, but it seems like the function isn't working properly! what could I be missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
    $productData = $observer->getProduct();
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productData->getId());
    $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product);
    $stockQty = $stock->getQty();
    if($stockQty>1){
    $stock->setManageStock(1)
          ->setUseConfigManageStock(1)
          ->setIsInStock(1);
     Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
     $stock->save();
  }
```